# Find rows in a GroupBy that exist in every group

Tags: sql

I have a temp table `#People` that holds something like this:

```
PersonnelId, TaskId
200          40
200          41
200          **42**
300          **42**
300          45
400          41
400          **42**
400          60
```

So notice **42** exists in ALL three groups of personnel.

How can I write a query that find this 42 for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will get the taskid that exists in all personnelId.

```
Select taskid
From tbl
Group by taskid
Having count(distinct PersonnelId) = 
  (select count(distinct PersonnelId) from tbl)
```